# Hadoop service not working

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop-conf-pseudo on ubuntu container through boot2docker. I tried to start the command using

```
service /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
```

It says

```
Starting hadoop-hdfs-namenode 
Started hadoop-hdfs0namenode
```

When i try to view it using ps to check whether it is running

```
PID  INFO
 1    sh
 7    ps
```

When i try jps, it says

```
PID INFO
53  process info unavail
 8  jps
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible. @sonic when i run inside dockerfile, i ma getting this error. but not inside a container